# ResourceExhaustedError - out of memory in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, nvidia, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

Below is my code snippet for alexnet like network(here input is 224*224 grayscale). I am getting the Resource Exhausted error posted below and I am not sure as to why

```
import tensorflow as tf
from IPython import embed
import pre_process_data as dataProc
import numpy as np

#Converting RGB to Gray
from skimage import color

#Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 200000
batch_size = 4 
display_step = 20

#Network Parameters
n_input = [224,224,3] # (img 224,224,3)
n_classes = 7 # (0-7)
dropout = 0.8 # Dropout

def ReturnOneHotVector(labels):
    labels = labels.astype(np.int32)
    sparse_labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1]) 
    derived_size = tf.shape(sparse_labels)[0]
    indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(0, derived_size, 1), [-1, 1]) 
    concated = tf.concat( [indices, sparse_labels],axis=1)
    outshape = tf.concat([tf.reshape(derived_size, [1]), tf.reshape(n_classes, [1])],axis=0)
    one_hot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated, outshape, 1.0, 0.0)
    return one_hot_labels

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return initial

def conv2d(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,W,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

#Build Graph
def deepnn(x_image):
    '''x - input [none, 224*224*3]
    returns y([none, 10], scalar keep_prob'''

    with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
        x_image = tf.reshape(x_image,[-1,224,224,1])

    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,W_conv1)+ b_conv1)   

    # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
    with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
        h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

    # Second pooling layer.
    with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
        h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    #FC layer
    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
        W_fc1 = weight_variable([56 * 56 * 64, 1024])
        b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

        h_pool2_flat=tf.reshape(h_pool2,[-1,56*56*64])
        h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat,W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    #Dropout
    with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
        keep_prob=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    #FC2
    with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
        W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024,7])
        b_fc2 = bias_variable([7])

        y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
    return y_conv, keep_prob 

def main():

    #Read input
    joints,imgs,labels = dataProc.pre_proc_data()

    labels = dataProc.ConvertLabels(labels)
    labels = ReturnOneHotVector(labels) #return labels as one-hot-vector
    imgs = color.rgb2gray(imgs)
    imgs = imgs.reshape([-1, imgs.shape[1]*imgs.shape[2]])

    embed()

    #-----------------NETWORK 1 -------------------------#

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,imgs.shape[1]])
    y_ = tf. placeholder(tf.int8,[None, n_classes])

    '''sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        embed()
    '''

    #Build convnet
    y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits = y_conv)
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

    with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
        correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)
    graph_location = '/home/dhiraj/Desktop/Sample Dataset/record' #tempfile.mkdtemp()
    print('Saving graph to: %s' % graph_location)
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_location)
    train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

    '''config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allocator_type='BFC'
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.90
    sess = tf.Session(config = config)
    '''
    '''config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
    session = tf.Session(config=config)
    '''

    with  tf.Session() as sess: 
        #tf.Session() as sess:
        print "STARTED TENSORLFOW SESSION"
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        step = 1
        count = 0 
        labels = labels.eval()
        while step*batch_size < training_iters:
            batch_xs, batch_ys = imgs[count:count + batch_size],labels[count:count+ batch_size]
            count = count + batch_size
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_:batch_ys, keep_prob:dropout})
            if step % display_step == 0:
                acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_:batch_ys, keep_prob:1.})
                loss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.})
                print "Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc)

            step = step+1
        print "Optimization Finished!"            

main()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
name: TITAN X (Pascal)
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.531
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.90GiB
Free memory: 11.23GiB
2017-09-16 16:16:14.018792: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-09-16 16:16:14.018797: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-09-16 16:16:14.018809: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
STARTED TENSORLFOW SESSION
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py:175: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
Iter 80, Minibatch Loss= 60.153133, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Iter 160, Minibatch Loss= 40.757141, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Iter 240, Minibatch Loss= 24.546730, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Iter 320, Minibatch Loss= 7.033617, Training Accuracy= 0.25000
Iter 400, Minibatch Loss= 9.611395, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Iter 480, Minibatch Loss= 17.850220, Training Accuracy= 0.50000
Iter 560, Minibatch Loss= 9.400875, Training Accuracy= 0.00000
Iter 640, Minibatch Loss= 7.338353, Training Accuracy= 0.25000
Iter 720, Minibatch Loss= 3.645672, Training Accuracy= 0.25000
Iter 800, Minibatch Loss= 1.157605, Training Accuracy= 0.25000
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545341: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:244] tried to allocate 0 bytes
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545369: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/allocator_retry.cc:32] Request to allocate 0 bytes
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545375: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:244] tried to allocate 0 bytes
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545379: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/allocator_retry.cc:32] Request to allocate 0 bytes
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545433: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:378] tried to deallocate nullptr
2017-09-16 16:16:31.545482: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:378] tried to deallocate nullptr
-----------------------------------------------------------
[SOME TEXT HERE ]
    ResourceExhaustedError: Ran out of GPU memory when allocating 0 bytes for 
         [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]

    Caused by op u'loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits', defined at:
      File "tensorflow_version_rgb.py", line 162, in <module>
        main()
      File "tensorflow_version_rgb.py", line 117, in main
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits = y_conv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1597, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
        precise_logits, labels, name=name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2385, in _softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
        features=features, labels=labels, name=name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
        op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
        original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
        self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): Ran out of GPU memory when allocating 0 bytes for 
     [[Node: loss/SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](loss/Reshape, loss/Reshape_1)]]
```

My code's iteration depends on the batch size, if I reduce it to 1 it runs fora couple of more iterations and then gives me the same error. I checked the size of my  `imgs.nbytes` which is **334774272** bytes. I have run other tensorflow tutorial code and it seems to work fine.

My input data 'imgs' is of size (834, 224,224) sized gray scale images and labels is (834,7) matrix.

While running the above code, it say:

```
Total memory: 11.90GiB
Free memory: 11.23GiB
```

output of my NVIDIA-SMI when the code is running is :
[image: nvidia-smi]

Comment: If in `imgs[count]`, `count` is out of order, what will happen? and the error happens when the iteration approaches 834. I don't think it's a coincidence. You can check it.

Comment: You are right!the error above is produced because count went out of order. Pretty embarrassing mistake I should say. Thanks for the catch!